# exercise in Shafarevich

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

I didn't know what is the meaning of two elements, I just found that xy+xz+yz=0 and xy+xz-yz=0 can satisfy the requirement.

Shafarevich--Basic Algebraic Geometry 1 P80

Comment: Welcome to mathstackexchange! Could you please tell us exactly which exercise in (which book by) Shaferevich you are referring to?

Comment: The question is about the ideal of polynomials that vanish on all three axes. For example $xy,xz$ and $yz$ are such polynomials. You can write $yz$ as a combination of $p_1=xy+xz+yz$ and $p_2=xy+xz-yz$, because $yz=(p_1+p_2)/2$. But I don't see a way of getting the other two.

Comment: I mean if the ideal is generated by xy+xz+yz=0 and xy+xz-yz=0 which vanish on all three axes.

Comment: Thanks, I mistake some notions, now I am clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're claiming that $xy+xz+yz$ and $xy+xz-yz$ generate the ideal because any zero of both equations lies on one of the three axes, and that those two equations vanish on the three axes.  By the nullstellensatz, that means that the radical of the ideal generated by those two elements is the ideal of the curve whose components are the $3$ coordinate axes.

However, this ideal is not radical. Notice that $xy \notin I$ but $(xy)^2 \in I$.

Comment: Thank you, I mistake some notions. There are so many notion in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Can you give me some hints about this question? Thanks.

Comment: $I$ is graded with no elements of degree less than $2$ and $3$ linearly independent quadratic terms.  That's not going to be possible with $<3$ generators.